# jQuery $.get() not working properly

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a problem with an extremely simple $.get() request. When I tested it with the error handling functions, it triggered the Error and Complete functions. Also, if I run the php file straight from my URL bar in my browser it works perfectly. Here is my code:

Inline JS: [located in root]

```
$.get('php/getRank.php', function(teamRank) {
    alert("Your team has finished with rank: " + teamRank);
});
```

PHP: [located in root/php]

```
require_once '../includes/constants.php';

$con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    } 
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con);

session_start();

*/ CALCULATE RANK HERE */

echo $rank;
```

Are there some PHP limitations or something when using $.get()? All I wanted to do is execute a PHP script from JS. Should I use something other than $.get()?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the error you are getting (add `console.log(arguments)` in your error handler).

Comment: remember: ajax is just an http request. PHP cannot tell that the hit coming in was triggered by someone clicking a link, submitting a form, or in the background by some JS code - it just sees a request. If you don't see a hit in the server's log when the ajax stuff fires up, then you'll have to figure out why the JS code isn't working.

Comment: It seems adding .error(console.log(arguments)) actually makes the whole $.get call work...does that make any sense?

Comment: It does not make sense, but it does tell us that you aren't using the latest version of jQuery. .error on a jqXHR object has been removed as of 1.9, it was depreciated some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

session_start() usually is the first statement in PHP